# Sharepoint FBA Registeration

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

in SharePoint 2010 server environment and a site collection that use FBA Authentication , how do i allow anonymous users to register ?

any help on that ? any tutorial ? i have searched for awhile and cant find something useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharepoint does not come with any kind of registration pages.  You have to build them yourself or use a third party tool.

The Sharepoint 2010 FBA Pack has registration pages you can use.  Check it out:
   http://sharepoint2010fba.codeplex.com/